# Android. Как организовать выбор стилей в приложении?

Tags: android, ui, интерфейс

Родилась, банальная мысль: сделать в приложении возможность менять стили. Т.е. пользователь выбрал в меню, из списка "Оранжевый" - раз, и все стало в оттенках оранжевого. Выбрал "Синий" - стало синенькое. 
Создал несколько стилей, с разной раскраской. И возник вопрос, как организовать заполнение меню? 
Получилось так:

```
    menu.add(R.id.themesMenuGroup, R.style.AppThemeBlack, 0, R.string.AppThemeBlackName);
    menu.add(R.id.themesMenuGroup, R.style.AppThemeBrown, 0, R.string.AppThemeBrownName);
    menu.add(R.id.themesMenuGroup, R.style.AppThemeAmber, 0, R.string.AppThemeAmberName);

// ------- еще много аналогичных строк выброшено для экономии места -----------
```

Но, как-то это громоздко. И родился у меня вопрос, а нельзя ли как-то иначе заполнить это меню со списком стилей?

Comment: y UI компонентов вы можете динамически менять стили, в чем вопрос то? с меню не можете разобраться?

Comment: Нет, вопрос в том, как заполнить меню в цикле, чтобы не писать 15 строк добавления пунктов меню. А для этого надо как-то обойти все стили, а они прописаны в классе R.style как статические поля. Вот думаю, что надо через рефлексию это делать. Но засомневался, вдруг есть более нативный способ.

Comment: забросьте все в массив, R.style... это обычный int, и пробежитесь циклом. рефлексить меню и лезть в natice не надо)) вдруг всё поломается.

Comment: Извиняюсь за тупость, забросить в массив как? Тупо перечислив 15 ресурсов?  Это же те же яйца. Я же горожу это все не ради красоты кода, а чтобы, когда добавился новый стиль, он сам появился в меню.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через рефлексию все таки получилось. Создал класс, который предоставляет доступ к стилям для выбора и заполняет переданное ему меню. Покритикуйте пожалуйста.

```
public class StyleHelper {
private static StyleHelper instance;
private ArrayList<ContentValues> styleValues;

private StyleHelper(){
}

private void init(){
    styleValues = new ArrayList<>();
    Field[] styleFields = R.style.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i=0; i<styleFields.length; i++){
        Field styleField = styleFields[i];
        String styleName = styleField.getName();
        if (styleName.startsWith("AppTheme")){
            try {
                ContentValues styleValue = new ContentValues();
                styleValue.put("style",styleFields[i].getInt(styleName));
                styleValue.put("name",R.string.class.getField(styleName+"Name").getInt(styleName+"Name"));
                styleValues.add(styleValue);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void fillMenu(Menu menu, int groupId){
    for (ContentValues styleValue: styleValues) {
        menu.add(groupId,styleValue.getAsInteger("style"),0,styleValue.getAsInteger("name"));
    }
}

public static StyleHelper getInstance() {
    if (instance==null){
        instance = new StyleHelper();
        instance.init();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

}